# Append an element while grabbing the id of the parent element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Let me just preface this by saying I am infact using jQuery so I can make use of their available functions.

I have some HTML setup like so

```
<div id=12 class="comp">
  <div class="random">
    <div class="addHere">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id=34 class="comp">
  <div class="random">
  </div>
</div>
<div id=56 class="comp">
  <div class="random">
    <div class="addHere">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And I want to add an input element after each element with the class name "addHere". Easy enough, however I would like each of those inputs to have a class which is the same as the id of the most parent element with the class "comp", this means that in the end it should look like this

```
<div id=12 class="comp">
  <div class="random">
    <div class="addHere">
      <input type="text" class="12">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id=34 class="comp">
  <div class="random">
  </div>
</div>
<div id=56 class="comp">
  <div class="random">
    <div class="addHere">
      <input type="text" class="56">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I achieve this? The only way I can think of is looping over each element with class name comp and checking if it has the class "addHere" anywhere in it, and if it does, save the id to an array and then find all "addHere" elements and loop through that whilst adding the id gotten from the previous array.

It works, but I'm still a little new to this sort of front-end related js and this involves looping over twice so I'm hoping there's another cleaner way.

Comment: You can't have multiple IDs in the same file - it's invalid HTML. Consider using a class.

Comment: Ah right, in my actual code I use data fields. Just wrote this small template for a quick example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by looping over each `addHere` div using the `.each()` method and then get its parent div with the class `.comp` using `.closest()`. Once you have got its parent you can use the `.attr("id")` to get it's `id`.

Lastly, you can then `.append()` the element to your `.addHere` div.

However, it is invalid HTML to have multiple elements with the same `id`, instead, you should use a `class`:

```js
$(".comp .addHere").each(function() {
  const id = $(this).closest(".comp").attr("id");
  $(this).append(`<input type='text' value='${id}' class='${id}'/>`);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id=12 class="comp">
  <div class="random">
    <div class="addHere">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id=34 class="comp">
  <div class="random">
  </div>
</div>
<div id=56 class="comp">
  <div class="random">
    <div class="addHere">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is perfect, thank you! And yeah I wrote the id by accident, not using that in my actual code :P

Comment: @HelloMellow ah I see, no worries :)

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('.comp').find('.addHere').map(function(index, item){     
  $(item).append(` <input type="text" id="${$(this).parents('.comp').attr('id')}">`)
})
```

```html
<div id=12 class="comp">
  <div class="random">
    <div class="addHere">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id=34 class="comp">
  <div class="random">
  </div>
</div>
<div id=56 class="comp">
  <div class="random">
    <div class="addHere">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```